# Sending XML through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I create a xml document in jQuery as following

```
var xmlDocument = $('<xml/>');
var foo = $('<foo/>');
var bar = $('<bar/>');

foo.append(bar);
xmlDocument.append(foo);
```

and try to forwards it to the server.

```
$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   precessData     :   false,
   contentType     :   'text/xml',
   data            :   xmlDocument,
   sucess          :   function( data ) {
      alert('success');
   },
   error           :   function() {
      alert('failed to send ajax request');
   },
   complete        :   function() {
      alert('ajax request completed');
   }
});
```

Even if the server echos a 'foo' only, I get the `alert('ajax request completed')` and not the `alert('success')`. What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I'm creating the xml document or is it the way I forward it to the server?

An ajax request without a xml document works fine and I get the 'foo' back.

**UPDATE #1**

After changing **precessData** to **processData** and **sucess** to **success** i get the `failed to send ajax request` dialog.

When I change the data parameter in the ajax method to

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   data :   {
      data: xmlDocument
   },
   ...
});
```

I also get the `failed to send ajax request` dialog.

The code on the server side should be fine cause it's only

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
?>
```

**UPDATE #2**

I converted my string as in AndreasAL's answer

```
// Convert to string instead of DOM Elements
xmlDocument = $("<wrap/>").append(xmlDocument).html();

// Url encode the string
xmlDocument = encodeURIComponent(xmlDocument);
```

but i still get the same dialog box (`failed to send the ajax request`). So i thought the error could be in my xml document and overwrote my xml document by using the code snipplet from AndreasAL's answer.

```
xmlDocument = $('<xml/>');
foo = $('<foo/>').appendTo(xmlDocument);
bar = $('<bar/>').appendTo(foo);
```

Still the same behaviour.

So I checked my xml document again and printed it in a dialog box and it looks fine.

I'm running out of ideas where the error could be ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I decided to convert the xml document and send it as a string to the server.

```
$xmlString = $(xmlDocument).html();
```

Due to the fact, that I only have to store the recieved data, it makes no difference if I'm revieving it as string or xml.

I only had to change my ajax request at everything works fine now.

```
$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   data            :   'data=' + xmlString,
   success         :   function( data ) {
      alert(data);
   },
   error           :   function() {
      alert('failed to send ajax request');
   },
   complete        :   function() {
      alert('ajax request completed');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

You have a typo - it's not `precessData` it's `processData`

```
$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   precessData     :   false, // change to processData
```

and again in `sucess` which should be `success`

---

Try:

```
var xmlDocument = $('<xml/>'),
    foo = $('<foo/>').appendTo(xmlDocument),
    bar = $('<bar/>').appendTo(foo);
```

---

```
// Convert to string instead of DOM Elements
xmlDocument = $("<wrap/>").append(xmlDocument).html();

// Url encode the string
xmlDocument = encodeURIComponent(xmlDocument);


$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   processData     :   false,
   contentType     :   'text/xml',
   data            :   xmlDocument,
   success         :   function( data ) {
      alert('success');
   },
   error           :   function() {
      alert('failed to send ajax request');
   },
   complete        :   function() {
      alert('ajax request completed');
   }
});
```

Comment: omg, i really misstyped it. But now I get the 'failed to send ajax request' dialog.

Comment: Maybe if you convert to string as in example 2 . And fix your success handler.

Comment: I tried to convert the string, still the same behaviour. I also checked my xml document, but it looks fine. Also used the code snipplet to overwrite my xml document in case the error is there ... still the same behaviour.

Comment: are you sure your ajax call returns legit xml? You can in your `complete` method try to alert the second argument (`arguments[1]`) does it say `parser error`??

Comment: the complete method isn't called anymore but the error method says `null`

Comment: as in the request never success. Are you sure you have the right headers in your php file? I think thats the reason for the null. Try chancing your php file to output `<foo><bar></bar></foo>`

Answer (score 3):

You are using jQuery Object through the entire process.

Write your XML like this, concatenating the string together. Not making them as DOM Object.

```
var xmlDocument = '<xml/>';
xmlDocument += '<foo/>';
xmlDocument += '<bar/>';
```

Then post it, like this

```
$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   precessData     :   false,
   contentType     :   'text/xml',
   data            :   { 
                           data: xmlDocument //wrapped inside curly braces
                       },

   // Here is your spelling mistake
   success          :   function( data ) {
      alert('success');
   },
   error           :   function() {
      alert('failed to send ajax request');
   },
   complete        :   function() {
      alert('ajax request completed');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug on your code on success

```
$.ajax({
   url             :   'js/foobar.php',
   type            :   'POST',
   precessData     :   false,
   contentType     :   'text/xml',
   data            :   xmlDocument,
   success          :   function( data ) {
      alert('success');
   },
   error           :   function() {
      alert('failed to send ajax request');
   },
   complete        :   function() {
      alert('ajax request completed');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use $.parseXML to manipulate XML  , you are treating the xml as if it is html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
data : { xml: xmlDocument }
```

Post values need a key

Comment: I tried it but it isn't working out. I still get only the 'ajax request completed' as a dialog.