# Sending JSON to PHP - decoding issue

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to send a JSON object to a PHP file, which will then insert it into a database:

> ["[{"title":"Marriage (Same Sex Couples)","date":"20…personnel overseas, and for connected purposes.}]", "[{"title":"Energy","date":"2013-06-04","location":…ommissioning costs; and for connected purposes.}]", "[{"title":"Children and Families","date":"2013-06-…st flexible working; and for connected purposes}]", "[{"title":"Finance","date":"2013-06-04","location"…e further provision in connection with finance.}]", "[{"title":"Offender Rehabilitation","date":"2013-0…ed sentence orders, and for connected purposes.}]", "[{"title":"Care","date":"2013-06-04","location":"L…Research Authority, and for connected purposes.}]", "[{"title":"Mesothelioma","date":"2013-06-04","loca…t the resolution of certain insurance disputes.}]"]
>   0: "[{"title":"Marriage (Same Sex Couples)","date":"2013-06-04","location":"Lords","billtype":"Government Bill", "linkurl":"http://services.parliament.uk/bills/2013-14/marriagesamesexcouplesbill.html", "description":"A Bill to make provision for the marriage of same sex couples in England and Wales, about gender change by married persons and civil partners, about consular functions in relation to marriage, for the marriage of armed forces personnel overseas, and for connected purposes.}]"...
>   length: 7

The problem i am having is I dont know what it looks like, or how to deal with it at the php stage, so I can separate each line, and add it to the database.

```
<?php
include('sql.php');

$switch = $_POST['switch'];

switch ($switch) {

   case "rssAdd":

   $info[] = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);


   $sql = "INSERT INTO rssFeed (date, title, description, location, billtype, link) VALUES(". $info['date'] .",". $uid .", ". $voted .", NOW())";
    //$inres = $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo "worked: ".$info;

   break;
}
?>
```

Because I cannot see what $info looks like, or how it is decoded, i am really finding it hard to figure out.  Please can someone give me a point in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Worth also noting, that I console.log what I am sending to the PHP file, which were I am getting the JSON info.

Comment: Where is the XML? Or is this just a mistake in your question's title?

Comment: Good point, the data comes from a XML (rss feed), I then push it into a JSON in javascript, and then ajax it to php.  I would guess it was a mistake with the question.

Comment: You cannot see what `$info` looks like? `print_r($info)`.

Comment: You need to use `prepared statements` for this to work, as there's a lot of characters in that JSON string that you're not allowed to paste directly into the query. [**Take a look at the manual entry for MySQLi prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: ok first of all; you don't need a switch for one or two conditions; that's what an `if` is for, second; it looks like the json object is inside an array, so you'll have to get that first elemenet of the array and json_decode that element

Answer (score 3):

By looking at your JSON I think `json_decode($_POST['data'], true);` will return array of array, so you should use:

```
$info = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
foreach($info as $t)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rssFeed (date, title, description, location, billtype, link) VALUES(". $t['date'] .",". $uid .", ". $voted .", NOW())";
}
```

Also you can print your `$info` object using `print_r($info);` and see the output of `json_decode($_POST['data'], true);`

Comment: If I just print_r($info) or echo it back to the JS which console.log(result) its blank.  Does that mean the $info is empty ?

Comment: if `print_r($info)` displays nothing, it means that $info is null, i.e. `json_decode` has returned null, i.e. your JSON string cannot be decoded. In this case check your JSON string for correctness. Use any online JSON Validator to check if your JSON string is correct.

Comment: Correct, the json is not correct.  Can i move the XML via ajax rather than trying to make it to json and have php parse xml ? that.

Comment: Yes you can, I have not used XML with AJAX yet, so I cann't give an example, but you can get a basic idea about how to do this here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683313/sending-xml-through-ajax

Comment: Here is an good example about how to parse XML string in PHP using SimpleXML: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php